# Keras load_model is causing 'TypeError: Keyword argument not understood:' when using custom layer in model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am building a model with a custom attention layer as implemented in [Tensorflow's nmt tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention). I used the same layer code with a few changes which I found as suggestions in order to solve my problem.

The problem is that I cannot load the model from file after I save it when I have this custom layer. This is the layer class:

```
class BahdanauAttention(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim=30, **kwargs):
        super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        query = inputs[0]
        values = inputs[1]
        query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

        score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
            self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

        context_vector = attention_weights * values
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(BahdanauAttention, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            'W1': self.W1,
            'W2': self.W2,
            'V': self.V,
        })
        return config
```

I am saving the model with keras' `ModelCheckpoint` callback:

```
path = os.path.join(self.dir, 'model_{}'.format(self.timestamp))
callbacks.append(ModelCheckpoint(path, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min'))
```

Later, I am loading the model like so:

```
 self.model = load_model(path, custom_objects={'BahdanauAttention': BahdanauAttention, 'custom_loss': self.custom_loss})
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
    TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'W1')
```

and full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models/lstm.py", line 49, in load_model
    'dollar_mape_loss': self.dollar_mape_loss})
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 187, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 121, in load
    path, options=options, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 633, in load_internal
    ckpt_options)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 130, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 215, in _load_all
    self._layer_nodes = self._load_layers()
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 315, in _load_layers
    layers[node_id] = self._load_layer(proto.user_object, node_id)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 341, in _load_layer
    obj, setter = self._revive_from_config(proto.identifier, metadata, node_id)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 359, in _revive_from_config
    self._revive_layer_from_config(metadata, node_id))
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 417, in _revive_layer_from_config
    generic_utils.serialize_keras_class_and_config(class_name, config))
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 175, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 360, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 697, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "models/lstm.py", line 310, in __init__
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 318, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "venv/m/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 778, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'W1')
```

Similar questions suggest that the code is using different versions of Keras and TensorFlow. I am only using TensorFlow's Keras. These are the imports

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [keras' documentation on custom layers](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/), They recommend that any weights should not be initialized in `__init__()` but in `build()`. This way the weights do not need to be added to the config and the error will be resolved.

This is the updated custom layer class:

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=30, **kwargs):
        super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
      

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        query = inputs[0]
        values = inputs[1]
        query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

       
        score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
            self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

        context_vector = attention_weights * values
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(BahdanauAttention, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            'units': self.units,
        })
        return config
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.
I've tried a lot of methods and found that this method can be used.
first,build model

```
model = TextAttBiRNN(maxlen, max_features, embedding_dims).get_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

second, load weights:
I solved the problem with this:

```
model_file = "/content/drive/My Drive/dga/output_data/model_lstm_att_test_v6.h5"
model.load_weights(model_file)
```

then,we will find the modle can be use.

in this way,I avoided the previous questions.